# Writing Range Data Annotation with Fluent API in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, clean-architecture

## Description

As I'm trying to adopt *Clean Architecture*, I want to move away from **Data Annotations** and use **Fluent API** which, personally, I started to prefer a lot more.

However, I'm not too skilled in this way of implementing things.

### Range Annotation (Old approach)

What I was previously doing was to use the `Range` annotation to specify a **min** and a **max** for number properties like so:

```cs
public class Engine
{
    ...

    [Range(0, 10000)]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Horse power")]
    [Range(0, 1000)]
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Top speed")]
    [Range(0, 500)]
    public int? TopSpeed { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

### Configuration class (Cleaner approach)

Now, I'm trying to write the validation code in the **Configuration** class associated with the `Engine` entity.

The **entity** class:

```cs
public class Engine
{
    public int EngineId { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }
    public int? TopSpeed { get; set; }
    public int FuelId { get; set; }
    public int TransmissionId { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I currently have for the **Configuration class**:

```cs
using Carsurfer.Domain.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Carsurfer.Persistence.Configurations
{
    public class EngineConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Engine>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Engine> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(engine => engine.Size);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Questions

1. Is there something built in to Entity Framework Core for this?
2. Should I implement the `IValidatableObject` interface somehow?
3. Should the **Configuration** class be concerned with the *validation* of its entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there something built in to Entity Framework Core for this?

There is no Fluent API equivalent to `RangeAttribute` to the best of my knowledge.

> Should I implement the IValidatableObject interface somehow?

Implementing `IValidatableObject` won't enable you to use Fluent API for `RangeAttribute`. You would still have to use `DataAnnotation` attributes.

> Should the Configuration class be concerned with the validation of its
>   entity?

`IEntityTypeConfiguration` is meant to provide a clean way to separate the your `DbModel` configuration for `EntityFrameworkCore` to use. So typically such configuration class will contain schema level set up and validation (constraints, max values, relational configuration (where appropriate)).

The question you need to ask yourself is why you are even using `RangeAttribute` in the first place. It does not have any effect schema wise. You could be using it because you also use your entity classes for MVC in built validation. If that's the case and you share your entity (POCO) classes instead of having separate classes for your ViewModels or Dto's then you will have to just use a hybrid version where you separate data annotations that are EF Core related into `IEntityTypeConfiguration` classes and leave data annotations that are for MVC validation purposes as attributes. It is worth noting that `DisplayNameAttribute` is also irrelevant as far EF Core is concerned.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now, I understand that I've been looking at these **data annotations** wrongly. Also, I've come across a .NET library called [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) which is used by a couple of developers to implement validation.